# Set css for all inner div inside root div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML page like

```
<div class="root">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div>
     <p>description</p>
     <div>Sub one description</div>
     <div>
         <table>
           <tbody><tr><td><div>Flag</div></td></tr></tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
   </div>
<div>
```

How can I apply css background property to inner div inside table using class name root. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $('.root').find('div>table').css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: It should be `$('div.root table').find('div').css("background-color", "green");` Agree with you that using `find()` is faster.

Comment: This seems like overkill, I'm sure that jQuery is optimised to do this behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.root table div').css('background', '#ff0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do the following code to do that

here i have put background color as red

```
$('.root table div').css( "background", "red" )
```

Hope this answered your question.

Answer (score -2):

Just select the top most one using:

```
$(".root div").css("background-color", "blue");
```

Since the inner-most div is inside the bounds of the one above it, there's no point giving it the same background color.

Comment: This will also apply to the div between div.root and the table